# what type of regression can I do with a % outcome variable?

Tags: statistics, regression

I have a dataset of cancer patients with their region, race, gender, and a few other variables. I want to see which variables are most significant to the cancer. I was thinking of creating a rate of cancer patients divided by population in the region (county). And performing a linear regression using the rate % as the outcome.

However, rate isn't continuous, its bounded. I don't think you can use bounded variables as the outcome in a linear regression.

Is there any way I can build a prediction model or measure variable contributions with the data that I have?

summary: what type of regression can I do with a % outcome variable?

I was thinking of a linear regression but the outcome is % and bounded between 0-1.